# Combine INSERT with SELECT statement with custom values

Tags: mysql, select, insert, sql-insert, insert-select

I need to clean up my MySQL database and make a lot of new records based on the current state.
I need to insert this:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ($ID, "price_input_currency", "usd")
```

For each $ID I get from this selection:

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts AS posts
RIGHT JOIN wp_postmeta ON posts.ID = post_id
WHERE post_type = 'post'
AND meta_value LIKE '%$%' AND meta_key = 'price_range'
```

Is this possible through only a MySQL code?
I've seen a bunch of "how to combine INSERT with SELECT, but none of them used just strings to insert, they always SELECTED ALL the fields they needed to insert...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `INSERT INTO...SELECT` construct, with constant string values for the `meta_key` and `meta_value` columns:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT ID, 'price_input_currency', 'usd'
FROM wp_posts AS posts
RIGHT JOIN wp_postmeta
    ON posts.ID = post_id
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND
    meta_value LIKE '%$%' AND meta_key = 'price_range'
```